# Transition doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a question about transition, i am trying to create a custom collapsible sidebar, using transition. What is meant to happen, is that the #nav appears as soon as the image is hovered over. But somehow this doesn't work, please help.

```
    #menu{
    width: 1.75em;
    height: 1.75em;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#title{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 5%;
    font-size: 210%;
    float: left;
}

#nav{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

#menu:hover #nav{
    width: 50%;
```

```js
function giveAlert(){
 alert("Your costum button works!");
}
```

```css
/* Stylesheet voor Eric's meetcabine */
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
/* Opmaak voor Tablets */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (max-height: 600px){
 #header{
  background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
  height: 7.5%;
 }
 
 #menu{
  width: 1.75em;
  height: 1.75em;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
 }
 
 #title{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 5%;
  font-size: 210%;
  float: left;
 }
 
 #nav{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
 }
 
 #menu:hover  #nav{
  width: 50%;
 }
 #navigation{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
 }
 li{
  display: inline;
 }
 li a{
  background-color: grey;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;  /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
 }
 li a:hover{
  background-color: #607d8b; /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
 }

 #section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
 }
 #buttons{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 #buttonlist{    /*da*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #buttoncontainer{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #button{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 #button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #graph{
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 
 #table{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 #footer{
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
}


/* Opmaak voor Desktops en Laptops en tablets*/
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (min-height: 600px){
 #header{
  background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
  height: 7.5%;
 }
 
 #title{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  margin: 0%;
  font-size: 375%;
 }
 
 #nav{
  background-color: grey;
 }
 
 #navigation{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
 }
 li{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
 }
 li a{
  background-color: grey;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;  /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
 }
 li a:hover{
  background-color: #607d8b; /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
 }

 #section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
 }
 #buttons{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
 }
 #buttonlist{    /*da*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #buttoncontainer{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #button{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 #button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #graph{
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
 }
 
 #table{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
 }
 
 #footer{
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Eric's meetcabine</title>
 <link href="./favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="header">
  <img src="menu.png" id="menu">
  <h1 id="title">Eric's meetcabine</h1>

 </div>
 
 <div id="nav">
  <ul id="navigation">
   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#meting">Meting</a></li>
   <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div id="section">
  <div id="buttons">
   <ul id="buttonlist">
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Coffee</a></li>
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Tea</a></li>
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Milk</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="table"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="footer"><center>&#169; Protonic</center></div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.
Sorry for my terrible language skills,
I am from the Netherlands.

Comment: I haven't tested your code to see the exact problem but this selector - `#menu:hover + #nav{` is wrong. The `#menu` element in your code is not a sibling of `#nav`.

Comment: I have corrected my code a bit, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, also I changed `#nav{ top:0; }` to `#nav{ top:27px; }` to avoide the problem where when the `#nav` section expands it will cover the `#menu` toggle and the "hover" effect won't work making quirky animation.

Also change this selector `#menu:hover ~ #nav` to this `#menu:hover ~ #nav, #nav:hover` so that the `#nav` section will stay expanded when you hover *away* from the `#menu` into the `#nav` section and won't transition back to it's original width.

[**JS Fiddle**-*updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/hm7c7fum/2/)

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
    /* code */
    top: 27px;
    /* code */
}
#menu:hover ~ #nav, #nav:hover{
    width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
  <img src="menu.png" id="menu">
  <h1 id="title">Eric's meetcabine</h1>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#meting">Meting</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#help">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full Code:**

```js
function giveAlert() {
  alert("Your costum button works!");
}
```

```css
/* Stylesheet voor Eric's meetcabine */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
}
/* Opmaak voor Tablets */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (max-height: 600px) {
  #header {
    background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
    height: 7.5%;
  }
  #menu {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #title {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 5%;
    font-size: 210%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #nav {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
  }
  #menu:hover ~ #nav,
  #nav:hover {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  li {
    display: inline;
  }
  li a {
    background-color: grey;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
  }
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #607d8b;
    /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
  }
  #section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 88%;
  }
  #buttons {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #buttonlist {
    /*da*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #buttoncontainer {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #button {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #button:hover {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #graph {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  #table {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Opmaak voor Desktops en Laptops en tablets*/

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (min-height: 600px) {
  #header {
    background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
    height: 7.5%;
  }
  #title {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    margin: 0%;
    font-size: 375%;
  }
  #nav {
    background-color: grey;
  }
  #navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
  }
  li a {
    background-color: grey;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
  }
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #607d8b;
    /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
  }
  #section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 88%;
  }
  #buttons {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  #buttonlist {
    /*da*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #buttoncontainer {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #button {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #button:hover {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #graph {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  #table {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="menu.png" id="menu">
  <h1 id="title">Eric's meetcabine</h1>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#meting">Meting</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#help">Help</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="section">
  <div id="buttons">
    <ul id="buttonlist">
      <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Coffee</a>
      </li>
      <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Tea</a>
      </li>
      <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Milk</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="table"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <center>&#169; Protonic</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i've moved the <div id="nav"> into the header, and everything seems to work now, thanks

Comment: You welcome @BartAdmiraal, check my updated answer I fixed two issues with these little changes

Answer (score 0):

Check Below, this code is work transition

```js
function giveAlert(){
 alert("Your costum button works!");
}
```

```css
/* Stylesheet voor Eric's meetcabine */
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
/* Opmaak voor Tablets */
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (max-height: 600px){
 #header{
  background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
  height: 7.5%;
 }
 
 #menu{
  width: 1.75em;
  height: 1.75em;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
 }
 
 #title{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 5%;
  font-size: 210%;
  float: left;
 }
 #nav{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
 }
 #nav:hover{
  width: 500px;
 }
 #navigation{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
 }
 li{
  display: inline;
 }
 li a{
  background-color: grey;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;  /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
 }
 li a:hover{
  background-color: #607d8b; /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
 }

 #section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
 }
 #buttons{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 #buttonlist{    /*da*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #buttoncontainer{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #button{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 #button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #graph{
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
 }
 
 #table{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
 #footer{
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
}


/* Opmaak voor Desktops en Laptops en tablets*/
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) and (min-height: 600px){
 #header{
  background: linear-gradient(white, gray);
  height: 7.5%;
 }
 
 #title{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  margin: 0%;
  font-size: 375%;
 }
 
 #nav{
  background-color: grey;
 }
 
 #navigation{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
 }
 li{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
 }
 li a{
  background-color: grey;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;  /*To remove the blue onderlines*/
 }
 li a:hover{
  background-color: #607d8b; /*Blue-grey from matterialize*/
 }

 #section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 88%;
 }
 #buttons{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
 }
 #buttonlist{    /*da*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #buttoncontainer{
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #button{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 #button:hover{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
 }
 
 #graph{
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
 }
 
 #table{
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
 }
 
 #footer{
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Eric's meetcabine</title>
 <link href="./favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="header">
  <img src="menu.png" id="menu">
  <h1 id="title">Eric's meetcabine</h1>

 </div>
 
 <div id="nav">
  <ul id="navigation">
   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#meting">Meting</a></li>
   <li><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div id="section">
  <div id="buttons">
   <ul id="buttonlist">
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Coffee</a></li>
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Tea</a></li>
    <li id="buttoncontainer" onclick="giveAlert()"><a id="button" href="#help">Milk</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="table"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="footer"><center>&#169; Protonic</center></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer, but unfortunately its not the answer i am looking for. I am trying to that by hovering over the #menu

Comment: In #menu ID have only <h1 id="title">Eric's meetcabine</h1> heading
on Hover you need to expand heading?